# Conversion tracking not showing up on google ads from branch for apps

Tags: google-ads-api

We've tried refreshing our link IDs and manually activating the events through different devices, but no events are shown, for us to choose from on the conversion tracking table on google ads.

What could be the issue?

Tried refreshing IDs, and  manually activating events. Currently our IDs are active on google, though that doesn't seem to help.